# jQuery form won't submit with prevent default

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have set up some validation in jQuery which I want to run before the form is submitted. However, when I use 'preventDefault' and try to submit the form at the end when the validation has passed, it won't.

```
$(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(..... // validation done here
      ....
      if(error === 1){
         ....
      }
      if(error === 0){
       $('#signup').submit(); // not working
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: You may try something like this `if(have_any_errors){ e.preventDefault(); }`, move it from the top.

Comment: please add your html code, and maybe you can add `else{alert("error != 0")}` . you can also add `console.log(error); ` right before the `if` to check the value displayed in the javascript console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $(function(){
       $('#submit').click(function(e){

          if(..... ){// validation done here
          ....
          }
          if(error === 1){
             e.preventDefault();
          }
          else
          {
           $('#signup').submit(); // not working
          }
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the validation, then let it continue if everything is ok, if not call preventDefault.

```
$(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(e){

      if ... // validation done here

      if(error === 1){
       e.preventDefault();
       ...
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you'd prefer to handle `submit`-event: in this case you can just return `false` to prevent submitting.

```
$(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(e){
      if(..... // validation done here
      ....
      if(error === 1){
         ....
      }
      return (error === 0);           
   });
});
```